# redirect url twitter not working (codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, twitter

I'm using Elliot's Twitter Library for Codeigniter framework (http://www.haughin.com/code/twitter/), the setup went well. But after clicking on allow button on the twitter auth page, it redirected back to the twitter auth page again.

I read about this on here but couldnot find a good anwser to this problem.

Maybe someone has been experience the same thing and can hand me a sollution.

Txs in advance

Comment: Where is your page's code/contents? Usually, that happens when your page does not detect if the user already came from Twitter.

Comment: within the libary there is the tweet_test....so i am using this to let myself being redirect to the auth page ....so thats were the thing goes wrong.. example can be found at http://ontruimingsvonnis.nogeven.nl/tweet_test so you can see for yourself..thanks in advance

Comment: This happened to me when trying to use CI 1.7.3. After upgrading to Reactor, it worked without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a circular redirect. I have written this article on how to integrate Twitter using CodeIgniter:

http://ferdychristant.com/blog//archive/DOMM-8B5JTP

Sell promotion: Yes: Relevant: Yes (I hope)